# Change the start of the year in the datetime module of Python?

Tags: python, datetime

Is there a way to change the start of the year in the datetime module of Python, from January to February?

I need the change because Wal-Mart starts their year the first week of February. I am writing a script that gets my schedule from their site and all their weeks are 4 weeks from the actual calender week.

Comment: Of course there is. It's in the source code of the module. Either change a local copy, or monkeypatch the part that you want to change.

Comment: Why do you need this? May be you need Chinese lunar calendar implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use timedelta

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
fourweeks = datetime.now() + timedelta(weeks=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the thing you are really looking for is to implement Chinese lunar calendar there is already an implementation called [lunardate](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lunardate).